# How to hide url after domain in web2py?

Tags: python, url, web, web2py

I am building a website using web2py. For security reasons I would like to hide the url after the domain to the visitors. For example, when a person clicks a link to "domain.com/abc", it will go to that page and the address bar shows "domain.com".

I have played with the routes_in and routes_out, but it only seems to map your typed url to a destination but not hiding the url.

How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a routing issue, and there's nothing specific in web2py to handle this. You would probably either have put the entire site inside an iframe or create a single page app with all server communication handled via Ajax and/or websockets. As Trent pointed out, though, keep in mind that it will generally be fairly easy for someone to see the requests the browser makes, so you won't really be buying any significant security using these methods.

Answer (score 1):

Well I guess you're going to have a build the worlds most remarkable single page application :) Security through obscurity is never a good design pattern.

There is absolutely no security "reason" for hiding a URL if your system is designed in a such a way that the use of the URLs is meaningless unless the access control layer defines permissions for such use (usually through an authentication and role/object based permission architecture).

Keep in mind - anyone these days can use Chrome inspector to see whatever you are trying to hide in the address bar.

For example. Say you want to load domain.com/adduser

Sure you make an AJAX call to that URL, and the browser address bar would never change from domain.com/ - but a quick look in the source will uncover /adduser pretty quickly.

Sounds like you need to have a think about what these addresses really expose and start locking them down.